# Is there a way to have a slider in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

So I was wondering if there was a way to have a slider in AppleScript. I found [this Apple Community post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2005922) which talks about how to read sliders from certain applications but I want to display a slider with a certain range. So I would like it to look somewhat like this:

```
set theSlider to slider from 1 to 10 with prompt "Set your number"
```

I don't think it exists but I wanted to be sure since it would be handy from time to time.

Comment: Creating a _slider object_ in  _basic vanilla_ **AppleScript** is not possible. It might be doable with **AppleScriptObjC**, however, someone else would have to  confirm that one way to the other.

Comment: @user3439894 Would there be a way of doing something similar without just display a list of 1 to 10?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/scripting/gui/dialog_examples.html --- BTW I do not know if this product still works with modern current releases of **macOS**.

Comment: @user3439894 It does not work with MacOS 11 at least.

Comment: So much for "21st century technologies unveiled by an industrial-strength environment." as it states on its home page.

Comment: The slider would need to be in a window or dialog (the accessory view of an NSAlert, for example) - how are you planning to use it?

Comment: To set a number that doesn't have to be precise. I'm aware that it has to be in a dialog, it should be similar to `display dialog` or `choose from list`.

Comment: It would be like `display alert`, with an added accessory view containing the slider.  The number may not need to be precise, but a description of _exactly_ what you are doing needs to be.  For example, the number range, whether they are integers, will tick marks do or does there need to be a text field for feedback, how this fits into the rest of your script (my current example is about 60 lines), etc.

Comment: The numbers need to be integers. As stated in the example above, 1 to 10 would be great. I don't quite understand what you mean with will tick marks but there is no need for a text field. The slider should set a value which determines how many times something should repeat. If you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: @user3439894 Smile is an option, it's just that the main release doesn't work on MacOS 11 and only the Beta release does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, regular **AppleScript** doesn't have anything like that, but the Cocoa frameworks can be utilized with some **AppleScriptObjC**.

The **NSAlert** class is what is used for `display alert`, but since you can't get inside **StandardAdditions** for customization, you will need to build the alert yourself.  In this example, I'm creating an **NSAlert** (hiding the bold text field a little bit), and using an **NSSlider** as an accessory view.  The response from the alert is a record consisting of the name of the button pressed and the value of the slider.

User interface items such as windows need to be run on the main thread; the `run` handler figures that out since Script Editors usually run scripts in their own threads.

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property response : missing value -- result from the alert

on run -- UI items need to be run on the main thread
    if current application's NSThread's isMainThread() as boolean then
        doStuff()
    else
        my performSelectorOnMainThread:"doStuff" withObject:(missing value) waitUntilDone:true
    end if
end run

to doStuff()
    try
        showAlert given info:"This is an example using a slider.", buttons:{"OK", "Whatever"}
        -- do stuff with the response
        log response
    on error errmess
        display alert "Error with doing stuff" message errmess
    end try
end doStuff

to showAlert given message:message : "Alert", info:info : "", buttons:buttons : {"OK"} -- reverse order
    set accessory to makeSlider of {275, 26} given initial:0, minimum:0, maximum:10
    tell current application's NSAlert's alloc's init()
        set its |window|'s autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop to true -- hook added views into the key-view loop
        
        # cheats to 'hide' the alert's bold message text field, and increase the size
        # of the informative text field (comment or remove for normal operation):
        (its |window|'s contentView's subviews's item 5)'s setFont:(current application's NSFont's boldSystemFontOfSize:0.25) -- something small
        (its |window|'s contentView's subviews's item 6)'s setFont:(current application's NSFont's systemFontOfSize:13) -- something bigger
        
        its setMessageText:message
        its setInformativeText:info
        repeat with aButton in buttons
            (its addButtonWithTitle:aButton)
        end repeat
        set its accessoryView to accessory
        set theButton to item ((its runModal() as integer) - 999) of buttons -- rightmost button returns 1000
        set response to {button:theButton, slider:(accessory's intValue) as integer}
    end tell
end showAlert

to makeSlider of |size| given origin:origin : {0, 0}, initial:initial : 0.0, minimum:minimum, maximum:maximum, action:action : missing value
    tell (current application's NSSlider's sliderWithValue:initial minValue:minimum maxValue:maximum target:me action:action)
        its setFrame:{origin, |size|}
        its setNumberOfTickMarks:(maximum + 1)
        set its allowsTickMarkValuesOnly to true
        # set other properties as desired
        return it
    end tell
end makeSlider
```

Comment: Are the `|` next to some variable names to prevent the system from seeing it as a reserved word or is it something AppleScriptObjC related?

Comment: Yes, the pipes are used where the variable name would otherwise be a reserved word or scripting term.  Something else such as `someSize` or `aSize` could be used, but that gets old sometimes.

Comment: OK, I was wondering because I tried to replace `|window|` with `theWindow` and it didn't work. The error is probably on my side.

Comment: In the `showAlert` handler, `window` is a property of the NSAlert.  `window`, `size`, and `error` are the more common Cocoa terms that AppleScript doesn't like.